# Does Python in Excel have the same Security issues as VBS in Excel?

Tags: malware, python, excel, macro

Microsoft Excel supports Python scripts ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-python-in-excel-a33fbcbe-065b-41d3-82cf-23d05397f53d)).

VBScript Macros within Excel are known to be a security risk ([source](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/guidance/macro-security-for-microsoft-office)). If I read [this emotet article](https://cybersecuritynews.com/king-of-malware-emotet-attack/) right, then VBScript macros allow arbitrary code execution.

**Do the included Python scripts have the same security issues as Excel VBScript Macros? Are the Python scripts sandboxed / restricted in any way?**

I don't have Microsoft Excel myself, hence I cannot simply try. I'd be especially curious if external requests (urllib3) or system execution (sys.exec) are possible.

[It seems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/open-source-libraries-and-python-in-excel-c817c897-41db-40a1-b9f3-d5ffe6d1bf3e) that a few external libraries can be used. But the set seems to closed, e.g. not arbitrary software can be used. As `beautifulsoup4` is in that list, I would guess that external requests can be made.

Comment: Please read the source you link to until the end and then you will find a link to [Data security and Python in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-security-and-python-in-excel-33cc88a4-4a87-485e-9ff9-f35958278327). Same link you get when you search for [python excel security](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+excel+security). There you can read about the security aspects. To cite a specific one: *"__The Python code does not have network access.__"*.

Comment: Sounds like the sandbox would be similar to VBA in Excel running in the "cloud".  Security-wise you should consider whether exposing your excel file to any "cloud" is acceptable.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Your link answers my question. Do you want to make it an answer or should I?

Comment: @MartinThoma: From my understanding the answer is too easy to find and basically contained in what you link to. So I don't see an added value of adding my own answer here. But feel free to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft provides the support page [Data security and Python in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-security-and-python-in-excel-33cc88a4-4a87-485e-9ff9-f35958278327) that answers most of this question:

Python in Excel runs in the Microsoft Cloud with the following attributes:

1. The Python code does not have network access.
2. The Python code does not have access to your computer, devices, or account.
3. The container has Python and a **curated** set of secured libraries provided by Anaconda.